# Name of $G(\lambda):=\mathbb{E}[X^{\lambda}]$

Tags: terminology

For a positive random variable, does the function
$$
G\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty]\\
G(\lambda):=\mathbb{E}[X^{\lambda}]
$$
have a name?

Comment: The $\lambda$th moment?

Comment: For each value of $\lambda$ we may call it the fractional moment of $X$. Or we may also consider it as the moment generating function of $\log X$. But I am not sure whether a specific name for $G$ is assigned in function viewpoint.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but im talking about the function, not just its value at one point

Comment: @SangchuiLee Thats exactly what I was looking for, I was dumb for not realizing that connection myself